# Braintree take time in opening PayPal

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree

I am implementing braintree on IOS Client in order to receive payments through credit cards and PayPal

But whenever I tap on PayPal it takes times to open it on browser, so in this mean time I want to show Loader so user can't feel any thing weird.

I am unable to find any delegate methods of **BTDropInController** which allow me to show loader when user press PayPal option.

Thanks in advance.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Can you update your question so that it meets [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Specifically, what is it you are trying to build and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: @BhavinRamani unfortunately No! :(

Comment: @hollabaq Due to confidence reasons I can't share business logic.But I can just share the specific scenario, let assume I am going to purchase xyz from my app, I tap to proceed button,  a braintree dropIn open, I select paypal as my payment method. It take me some time to open paypal web page. I want to show loader in this mean time.

Comment: @AhmedShahid if you are unable to create a [minimal, viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to help others understand your issue, feel free to contact [Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your activity indicator when you call paypal request from braintree. Below is the code for your reference:

```
    SVProgressHUD .show(withStatus: "Proccessing")

    let payPalRequest = BTPayPalRequest(amount: "1.20")
    payPalRequest.currencyCode = "USD"
    payPalRequest.landingPageType = .default
    payPalRequest.intent = .authorize
    payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(payPalRequest) { (tokenizedPayPalAccount, error) -> Void in
        if let tokenizedResult = tokenizedPayPalAccount{
            print("Get a nonce: \(tokenizedResult)")      

            SVProgressHUD .dismiss()

        }
    }
```